# How to extract metadata & open graph info when paste a link?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, facebook-opengraph, share-open-graph

I'm building a sort of sharing system where users can paste links and share with their friends.

I want to be able to extract information like title, description and images when the user pastes a link. Would be similar as Facebook or LinkedIn.

The system has a "sharebox" where the user write a comment and pastes a link. Before save it, I need to retrieve some metadata to complete the basic information about the link.

I'm building the system with ReactJS backed by a REST API in NodeJS.
Does anyone know about a package or library to do this?. Should be done in the Frontend, or needs interaction with the backend?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally http://embed.ly/ did the trick for me!.

Answer (score 1):

There are several [implementations](http://ogp.me/#implementations) for parsing [Open Graph](http://ogp.me) meta tags.

You could try one of the PHP libraries:

- [PHP Validator and Markup Generator](https://github.com/niallkennedy/open-graph-protocol-tools)
- [PHP Consumer](https://github.com/scottmac/opengraph)
- [OpenGraphNode in PHP](http://buzzword.org.uk/2010/opengraph/#php)

Comment: Thanks you. I was looking for a library more elaborate. I ended up using embed.ly(http://embed.ly/).